# Error on small screen

Tags: android-screen-support

I have the following code in my manifest.

```
<supports-screens android:resizeable="true"
              android:smallScreens="true" 
              android:normalScreens="true" 
              android:largeScreens="true"
              android:anyDensity="true"
              />
```

But it is not showing the complete screen in galaxy y.